# BIRT report charts are not visible in browser but data is displaying

Tags: jboss7.x, birt, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am using BIRT 4.2.0 and Jboss 7.1 I designed a report which consists of both charts and data, which is retrieved from my DB data is displaying correctly but charts are not displaying I am not getting any exception.
Any solution?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about jBoss 7.1 and not 1.7, which application are you using to generate reports (custom app, Eclipse webviewer,...)? Does it work in PDF format? Is your BIRT engine installed as a jboss module dependency, or is it embedded in the webapp generating reports?

Comment: this issue is critical, I m also facing the same problem but no succcess :(